# Correct Field Name For "Album Artist" ID3 Tag In SoX With LAME

Tags: tags, mp3, id3, sox, lame

I've got SoX compiled with LAME, and it works fine, I can make an .mp3 file with common ID3 tags.

But I can't figure out what to call the "Album Artist" field so that I can specify a value.
For example:

```
sox -n --comment "Title=Sweep" --comment "album_artist=ALBUM ARTIST TEST" input.mp3 synth 3 sine 20-20000
```

Will properly make a file that sounds like a sweeping sine wave, and the ID3 title will be "Sweep".
But the Album artist field is still blank.  I've tried several variations, to no avail:

band
bandname
albumartist
album_artist
group
orchestra
accompaniment
soloist
performer
leadperformer
TPE2, which is the technical name in ID3 for the field I'm trying to give a value.

But none of them seem to work.  Does anybody know the right "name" to use for this value?

Comment: The [Lame man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lame) doesn't mention the album artist field. According to [hydrogenaudio](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums//index.php?showtopic=79873) the field officially does not exist, but the post mentions **TXXX=ALBUM ARTIST=String1** which might be worth a try. Can't test it because I only have the official sox without lame.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
 sox --add-comment "Artist=Anonymous" ...
```

And while we're here, I also set other ID3v2 tags with sox:

```
--add-comment "Title=Le Tourdion Alto Learning" \
--add-comment "Album=Le Tourdion" \
--add-comment "Artist=Anonymous" \
--add-comment "Year=2019" \
--add-comment "Comment=2019-11-20T13:28:14+00:00"
```

Looking at the results using `id3info`:

```
$ id3info AltoLearning.mp3

*** Tag information for AltoLearning.mp3
=== TSSE (Software/Hardware and settings used for encoding): LAME 64bits version 3.100 (http://lame.sf.net)
=== TIT2 (Title/songname/content description): Le Tourdion Alto Learning
=== TPE1 (Lead performer(s)/Soloist(s)): Anonymous
=== TALB (Album/Movie/Show title): Le Tourdion
=== TYER (Year): 2019
=== COMM (Comments): ()[eng]: 2019-11-20T13:28:14+00:00
=== TLEN (Length): 56003
=== COMM (Comments): (ID3v1 Comment)[XXX]: 2019-11-20T13:28:14+00:00
```